# IIS Log field time-taken logs include network time, how to get time without network time?

Tags: iis, iis-8

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944884 IIS 6 and IIS 7 logs include network time unless response is smaller than 2 kb, does this changed on IIS 8, could not find relevant information.

If not, is there any other way to log time without network time on IIS 8 ?

update :

to clarify, I am allready analyizing IIS logs and I want to monitor time needed for IIS to complete request. It would be enough to get timings for ASP.NET pages, but don't wont to use ASP.NET trace, it seems as an overkill for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Time-to-first-byte is, strictly speaking, a client-side measure.

You might benefit from [Failed Request Tracing](http://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/archive/2012/08/14/enabling-failed-request-tracing.aspx) though, or for a more detailed view of the network stack operations on the web server, [WinHttp Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/03/21/winhttp-configuration-for-windows-vista.aspx)

Comment: well strictly speaking you are right, I will update my question. I want to log time needed to generate response